# Discord Slash Command: Error while sending Embeds

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was creating a slash command for my bot. So I tried this

```js
Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            content: 'hello world!'
        }
    }})
})
```

And this works fine.
So I tried sending an embed with it and tried these (2) code below

```js
Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            content: {
                embed: exampleEmbed
            }
        }
    }})
})
```

and

```js
Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            embed: exampleEmbed
        }
    }})
})
```

And none of these works.

So **what am I doing wrong ?**
Or, **How can I send an embed with slash command?**

Edit: This is how I define `exampleEmbed`

```js
const exampleEmbed = {
    color: 0x0099ff,
    title: 'Hello world',
    thumbnail: {
        url: 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png',
    },
    image: {
        url: 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png',
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It accepts an array of embeds, known as `embeds` property.

```js
Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            embeds: [ exampleEmbed ]
        }
    }})
})
```

From https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#responding-to-an-interaction

Answer (score 6):

For anyone using the discord.js API I use:

```
    const embed = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('testing');

    const messageId = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [ embed ] });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to send [embeds](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object) inside [`data`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#interaction-response-interactionapplicationcommandcallbackdata) as an array using the `embeds` property, but according to the docs *"Not all message fields are currently supported."*

```js
Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            content: 'hello world!',
            embeds: [exampleEmbed]
        }
    }})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is using discord.js for the embeds, you have to set the `type` property on the embed! You will get an error 400 otherwise.

```
import { MessageEmbed } from 'discord.js'

const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed({
    title: 'Error occurred',
    description: description,
    type: 'rich',
  });

Client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({data: {
        type: 4,
        data: {
            embeds: [exampleEmbed]
        }
    }})
})
```